# preg_replace extra double quote from Meta and Link tag for non-whitespace character?

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress

I have *meta* and *link* tag in *head*

**HTML Code**

```
<html><head>
<meta name="description" content="This is description of Example Sites 2018" />
<link href="https://examplesite.com/favicon.ico" rel="icon"/>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://example.com">Click Here</a>
</body></html>
```

**PHP Code**

```
preg_match("/([^\s]+)=\"([^\s]+)\"/i", $input_line, $output_array);
```

**Out Put**

```
<head>
<meta name=description content="This is description of Example Sites 2018" />
<link href=https://examplesite.com/favicon.ico rel=icon/>
</head>
<body>
<a href=https://example.com>Click Here</a>
</body>
```

**How Can I**

- execute this code only for head tag
- not for *link href=* and *a href=*
- only for non-whitespace character

Comment: What is the goal? Isn't the mark up in the head invalid as well?

Comment: actually, I working to minify HTML, just like GTMetrix doing. how can I get correct regex for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, it is better not to complicate your Regex(for maintenance purposes).
Thus, you can separate the extraction into three steps:

First, extract the `head` section(or exclude the body).

Secondly, exclude the `link` section.

Finally, use the Regex you wrote to extract it.